# Android: Delay an AudioTrack

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

I have an Android AudioTrack such as:

```
private AudioTrack mAudioTrack;
int min = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, min, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
mAudioTrack.play();
```

and I fill it with:

```
mAudioTrack.write(buffer, 0, bufsize);
```

I would like to have this track to be played with a 2-second delay. Any idea how I could achieve that? Thanks in advance for any good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer to my own question in case anybody is interested. The idea is to create a temporary buffer that creates and stores the audio "latency".

First, initialization:

```
final int mSizeTable = 300;
private byte[][] mTableAudioBuffer = byte[mSizeTable][];
private int mCountAudioBuffer = 0;
...
mAudioTrack.play();
```

Then, I fill with:

```
mTableAudioBuffer[mCountAudioBuffer] = buffer.clone();
int ret = 0;
if (mTableAudioBuffer[(mCountAudioBuffer + 1) % mSizeTable] != null)
    ret = mAudioTrack.write(mTableAudioBuffer[(mCountAudioBuffer + 1) % mSizeTable], 0, bufsize);
mCountAudioBuffer = (mCountAudioBuffer + 1) % mSizeTable;
return ret;
```

Obviously, memory-wise, it's not very optimal and can be greedy if you want a large delay.